# Transaction Broadcast error zcash

Tags: zcash

I can't broadcast the transaction to the zcash testnet. I will give the entire steps clearly. Could anyone tell me where I am doing wrong.This is my zcash address "tmRvLFZ3Lnz9vhd9bG2JuWakYESEi4ukxqs". Private key - "cSwoLKkeHSj3zaKAqiv8DXKXQVm18Ci3vwTvgrtPAS6a2YJ1HeRY"

```
step:1 zcash-cli listunspent 6 9999999 "[\"tmRvLFZ3Lnz9vhd9bG2JuWakYESEi4ukxqs\"]"
[
  {
    "txid": "8a1ce0ecc491ba2cb234674662769774ce81e4beaa7a7aff466aa62ea8b8345b",
    "vout": 1,
    "generated": false,
    "address": "tmRvLFZ3Lnz9vhd9bG2JuWakYESEi4ukxqs",
    "scriptPubKey": "76a914b1c61a54ae002ef35bf1fcdbdde9ea9e02b486bc88ac",
    "amount": 2.89999774,
    "confirmations": 16,
    "spendable": true
  }
]
```

step:2

```
    zcash-cli createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"8a1ce0ecc491ba2cb234674662769774ce81e4beaa7a7aff466aa62ea8b8345b\",\"vout\":1}]" "{\"tmGrqWFJQJtYXFwm6b4ptKpDetNTWdpc3kX\":0.4,\"tmFHNDXpWYgRQ44FXPidCiiq1Rfx9gESuQ1\":2.39999774}"
output for step-2 "030000807082c403015b34b8a82ea66a46ff7a7aaabee481ce74977662466734b22cba91c4ece01c8a0100000000ffffffff02005a6202000000001976a9144e63b9f685635c97f578c2e94f4aba622b65d11a88ac1e1b4e0e000000001976a9143d171848a9caf0a64b7f069b116675bca56ac08b88ac00000000a52a030000"
```

step:3

```
zcash-cli signrawtransaction "030000807082c403015b34b8a82ea66a46ff7a7aaabee481ce74977662466734b22cba91c4ece01c8a0100000000ffffffff02005a6202000000001976a9144e63b9f685635c97f578c2e94f4aba622b65d11a88ac1e1b4e0e000000001976a9143d171848a9caf0a64b7f069b116675bca56ac08b88ac00000000a52a030000" "[{\"txid\":\"8a1ce0ecc491ba2cb234674662769774ce81e4beaa7a7aff466aa62ea8b8345b\",\"vout\":1,\"scriptPubKey\":\"76a914b1c61a54ae002ef35bf1fcdbdde9ea9e02b486bc88ac\",\"amount\":2.89999774}]" "[\"private_key\"]"
output :
{
  "hex": "030000807082c403015b34b8a82ea66a46ff7a7aaabee481ce74977662466734b22cba91c4ece01c8a010000006a47304402201607a0454a641dc28a81324dd292275780fde44bbdec4d95131d0be35bcd591f0220601161a481a4b690076febf5c1c7508cddfd1972fda432b9bbc55d87289beb9c012103472fba697de28693fea3ea2d7a0d744d164d6264f8c4f44648eb904162387fe4ffffffff02005a6202000000001976a9144e63b9f685635c97f578c2e94f4aba622b65d11a88ac1e1b4e0e000000001976a9143d171848a9caf0a64b7f069b116675bca56ac08b88ac00000000a52a030000",
  "complete": true
}
```

step:4

```
zcash-cli sendrawtransaction "030000807082c403015b34b8a82ea66a46ff7a7aaabee481ce74977662466734b22cba91c4ece01c8a010000006a47304402201607a0454a641dc28a81324dd292275780fde44bbdec4d95131d0be35bcd591f0220601161a481a4b690076febf5c1c7508cddfd1972fda432b9bbc55d87289beb9c012103472fba697de28693fea3ea2d7a0d744d164d6264f8c4f44648eb904162387fe4ffffffff02005a6202000000001976a9144e63b9f685635c97f578c2e94f4aba622b65d11a88ac1e1b4e0e000000001976a9143d171848a9caf0a64b7f069b116675bca56ac08b88ac00000000a52a030000"
output:
error code: -25
error message:
```

Answer (score 0):

The Zcash testnet is currently in the midst of an upgrade. You need to upgrade your zcashd to at least 1.0.15, and it may be necessary to wait a while because the block frequency is artificially low at the moment.

Comment: This is my zcashd version : Zcash Daemon version v1.0.15. I am running on this version.